# Why use gradient descent for linear regression, when a closed-form math solution is available?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am taking the Machine Learning courses online and learnt about Gradient Descent for calculating the optimal values in the hypothesis.

```
h(x) = B0 + B1X
```

why we need to use Gradient Descent if we can easily find the values with the below formula? This looks straight forward and easy too. but GD needs multiple iterations to get the value.

```
B1 = Correlation * (Std. Dev. of y/ Std. Dev. of x)

B0 = Mean(Y) – B1 * Mean(X)
```

**NOTE:** Taken as in https://www.dezyre.com/data-science-in-r-programming-tutorial/linear-regression-tutorial

I did checked on the below questions and for me it was not clear to understand.

[Why is gradient descent required?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212619/why-is-gradient-descent-required)

[Why is optimisation solved with gradient descent rather than with an analytical solution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213271/why-is-optimisation-solved-with-gradient-descent-rather-than-with-an-analytical)

The above answers compares GD vs. using derivatives.

Comment: You don't need gradient descent to estimate linear regression coefficients.

Comment: @Sycorax "don't need" is a strong statement. Iterative method may be useful for huge data. Say data matrix is very big that cannot fit in memory.

Comment: @hxd1011 Thank you for clarifying this practical dimension to the problem. I was thinking in purely mathematical terms.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The main reason why gradient descent is used for linear regression is the computational complexity: it's computationally cheaper (faster) to find the solution using the gradient descent in some cases.

The formula which you wrote looks very simple, even computationally, because it only works for univariate case, i.e. when you have only one variable. In the multivariate case, when you have many variables, the formulae is slightly more complicated on paper and requires **much** more calculations when you implement it in software:
$$\beta=(X'X)^{-1}X'Y$$
Here, you need to calculate the matrix $X'X$ then invert it (see note below). It's an expensive calculation. For your reference, the (design) matrix X has K+1 columns where K is the number of predictors and N rows of observations. In a machine learning algorithm you can end up with K>1000 and N>1,000,000. The $X'X$ matrix itself takes a little while to calculate, then you have to invert $K\times K$ matrix - this is expensive.

OLS normal equation can take order of $K^2N$ operations to calculate coefficients in this setup. On the other hand one step of batch gradient descent is $KN$ order of operations, then if you take M steps the total is $KNM$. If you apply mini batch gradient technique with L mini batches, then one step complexity is $KMN/L$. Under typical conditions for machine learning algorithms, this can be much smaller than for OLS.

So, the gradient descent allows to save a lot of time on calculations. Moreover, the way it's done allows for a trivial parallelization, i.e. distributing the calculations across multiple processors or machines. The linear algebra solution can also be parallelized but it's more complicated and still expensive.

Additionally, there are versions of gradient descent when you keep only a piece of your data in memory, lowering the requirements for computer memory. Overall, for extra large problems it's more efficient than linear algebra solution.

This becomes even more important as the dimensionality increases, when you have thousands of variables like in machine learning.

**Remark**. I was surprised by how much attention is given to the gradient descent in Ng's lectures. He spends nontrivial amount of time talking about it, maybe 20% of entire course. To me it's just an implementation detail, it's how exactly you find the optimum. The key is in formulating the optimization problem, and how exactly you find it is nonessential. I wouldn't worry about it too much. Leave it to computer science people, and focus on what's important to you as a statistician.

Having said this I must qualify by saying that it is indeed **important to understand** the *computational complexity and numerical stability* of the solution algorithms. I still don't think you must know the details of implementation and code of the algorithms. It's not the best use of your time as a statistician usually.

**Note 1**. I wrote that you have to invert the matrix for didactic purposes and it's not how usually you solve the equation. In practice, the linear algebra problems are solved by using some kind of factorization such as QR, where you don't directly invert the matrix but do some other mathematically equivalent manipulations to get an answer. You do this because matrix inversion is an expensive and numerically unstable operation in many cases.

This brings up another little advantageof the gradient descent algorithm as a side effect: it works even when the design matrix has collinearity issues. The usual linear algebra path would blow up and gradient descent will keep going even for collinear predictors.

Comment: But Ng *is* a computer science person.

Comment: @amoeba, good for him, he's probably posting now on SO while we're hanging out here at CV :)

Comment: @hxd1011, if you're talking about the course then it's understandable given the target audience. his was the very first course in MOOC era, which pretty much started the whole thing. there's no way he could put linear algebra as a pre-requisite - nobody would sign up then.

Comment: Regarding your Remark: As a mathematician, I used to agree.  But my understanding now is that in modern machine learning, the method of optimization is inherently tied up with the objective being optimized.  Some forms of regularization, like dropout, are more cleanly expressed in terms of the algorithm instead of the objective.  In short: if you take a deep net, keep the objective function but change the optimization method, you may get very different performance.  In fact, sometimes a better optimizer yields worse results in practice ...

Comment: Minor nitpick: you'd certainly not *invert* $X'X$; instead you'd *solve* the linear equations system $X'X\beta=X'y$ for $\beta$. Abstractly, it's the same, but numerically, it's far more stable, and potentially even cheaper.

Comment: Id say more: $(X'X)^{-1}$ is sometimes ill-conditioned, thus regarthless of computational cost, it can yield a wrong result. Gradient descend does not need any inverse operator.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Solution with a QR factorization, on the other hand, is backward stable, hence it delivers a solution which is as accurate as possible given the uncertainty in the input data.

Comment: I think we should all stop writing $\beta = (X^t X)^{-1} X^t y$ and just write $X^t X \beta = X^t y$ all the time.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, why not $y=X\beta$? My point is that it's just an equation, it doesn't tell you how you solve it. The understanding is that $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ is not a literal machine instruction. On the other hand, it's simple and gets the point to beginners and also works for most of their toy problems. By the time they get to work on real problems, they'll know what's going on

Comment: @MatthewDrury agreed. That is why I have in my answer as solve the linear system $X^tX\beta=X^ty$, with the inversion is confusing. But, the advantage of writing in that from is hiding additional details for many people, that show we can have an analytical solution for $\beta$

Comment: @Aksakal This is a point that I disagree on.  I think that matrix inversion is not simple, and is not neccessary.  IMO we are confusing fundamental concepts in linear algebra (solving systems of linear equations) with secondary concepts (matrix inversion).  In terms of toy implementations, is `b = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y` really simpler than `b = solve(t(X) %*% X, t(X) %*% y)`?  I just don't think so.  This is a place we can make a tiny pedagogical change, and improve people's understanding.

Comment: @MatthewDrury, matrix inversion is not simple to implement, but as a mathematical concept it is. Trying to acknowledge its implementation difficulty is a good intent but it simply brings in something that's too early to worry about for those who're just getting into the regression.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Maybe we should stop using languages that perform a full inversion when you write `inv(X)*y` or `solve(X) %*% y`, instead. It takes very little syntactic sugar to return an object that performs a factorization and applies it when you multiply it by a vector.

Comment: @Aksakal great point on mathematical concept vs. implementation!

Comment: @MatthewDrury I am buying more for "mathematical concept vs. implementation". In math, the notation is defined by us. that we define matrix inversion as $XX^{-1}=I$, but how to calculate it / it is necessary or possible to calculate may not be an interest for math people.

Comment: I'm not making a point about implementation guys, I'm making a point about pedagogy (thought I do think the implementation is related to the pedagogy).  I think I'll open up a meta thread on this when I get a chance.

Comment: A nitpick: It might be that $X^T X$ isn't invertible. If you wish to invert it, as explained in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/363874/215801), one way to deal with that is removing from $X$ columns that are linear combinations of other columns.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/0324f50edbc096f0cb84430acdee666a) is a Python gist attempting to compute $(X^T X)^{+}X^T \vec{y}$ where $X$ is $10^6 \times 10^3$ in shape. It is *extremely* slow and requires a lot of virtual memory.

Answer (score 23):

In short, suppose we want to solve the linear regression problem with squared loss
$$\text{minimize}~ \|Ax-b\|^2$$ We can set the derivative $2A^T(Ax-b)$ to $0$, and it is solving the linear system
$$A^TAx=A^Tb$$

In high level, there are two ways to solve a linear system. Direct method and the iterative method. Note direct method is solving $A^TAx=A^Tb$, and gradient descent (one example iterative method) is directly solving $\text{minimize}~ \|Ax-b\|^2$.

Comparing to direct methods (Say [QR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) / [LU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) Decomposition). Iterative methods have some advantages when we have a large amount of data or the data is very sparse.

- Suppose our data matrix $A$ is huge and it is not possible to fit in memory, stochastic gradient descent can be used.  I have an answer to explain why [How could stochastic gradient descent save time compared to standard gradient descent?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232056/how-could-stochastic-gradient-descent-save-time-comparing-to-standard-gradient-d)
- For sparse data, check the great book [Iterative Methods for Sparse Linear Systems](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/%7Esaad/IterMethBook_2ndEd.pdf)

On the other hand, I believe one of the reasons Andrew Ng emphasizes it is because it is a generic method (most widely used method in machine learning) and can be used in other models such as logistic regression or neural network.

Comment: You are absolutely right. SGD is very helpful while handling a big amount of data. The method Prof Ng demonstrating is the most classic and pure one. One should start from that point to have a clear idea. If one can understand the motto of that then whole linear estimation will be crystal clear to him/her.

Comment: The size of the data maxtrix is not actually a problem, using the relationship $X^TX = \sum x_ix_i^T$; you can calculate $X^TX$ and $X^Ty$ one observation at a time.  This is actually how it was done in SAS back in the days when computer memory was far more limited than today.  It's the number of columns in $X$ that's the limiting factor.

Answer (score 8):

Sycorax is correct that you don't need gradient descent when estimating linear regression.  Your course might be using a simple example to teach you gradient descent to preface more complicated versions.

One neat thing I want to add, though, is that there's currently a small research niche involving terminating gradient descent *early* to prevent overfitting of a model.

Comment: For overfitting statement, could you provide the link? is adding the regularization term better than limiting number of the iterations?

Comment: You could look at Chapter 7 of Deep learning by Goodfellow et al , which mentions early stopping to prevent overfitting in neural nets.

Comment: Regularization by early stopping is by no means a new technique; it's a well known technique in, say, Landweber iteration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landweber_iteration

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, I think you are pointing towards the MOOC offered by Prof Andrew Ng. To find the optimal regression coefficients, grossly two methods are available. One is by using Normal Equations i.e. by simply finding out $(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}$ and the second is by **minimizing the least squares criterion** which is derived from the hypothesis you have cited. By the way, the first method i.e. the Normal equations is a product of the second method i.e. the optimization method.

**The method you have mentioned i.e. using correlation, it is applicable for one predictor and one intercept quantity only.** Just be noticing the form. So, when the number of predictors is more than one in number then what is the way out? Then one has to resort to the other methods i.e. the normal equation or optimization.

Now why optimization (here Gradient Descent) although direct normal equation is available. Notice that in normal equation one has to invert a matrix. Now inverting a matrix costs $\mathcal{O}(N^3)$ for computation where $N$ is the number of rows in $\mathbf{X}$ matrix i.e. the observations. Moreover, if the $\mathbf{X}$ is ill conditioned then it will create computational errors in estimation. So, it is the Gradient Descent kind of optimization algorithm which can save us from this type of problem. Another problem is overfitting and underfitting in estimation of regression coefficients.

My suggestion to you is don't go for merely solving a problem. Try to understand the theory. Prof Ng is one of the best Professors in this world who kindly teaches Machine Learning in MOOC. So, when he is instructing in this way then it must have some latent intentions. I hope you will not mind for my words.

All the best.

Comment: "Inverting a matrix" is strongly NOT recommended. QR is more numerically stable to solve a linear system.

Comment: I agree with the computational argument. However, over- or underfitting has nothing to do with using GD vs. the Normal equation, but rather with the complexity of the (regression) model. Both methods (GD if it works properly) find the same least-squares solution (if it exists), and will therefore over- or under-fit the data by the same amount.

Answer (score 2):

First, yes, the real reason is the one given by Tim Atreides; this is a pedagogical exercise.

However, it is possible, albeit unlikely, that one would want to do a linear regression on, say, several trillion datapoints being streamed in from a network socket. In this case, the naive evaluation of the analytic solution would be infeasible, while some variants of stochastic/adaptive gradient descent would converge to the correct solution with minimal memory overhead.

(one could, for linear regression, reformulate the analytic solution as a recurrence system, but this is not a general technique.)

Answer (score 2):

One other reason is that gradient descent is more of a general method. For many machine learning problems, the cost function is not convex (e.g., matrix factorization, neural networks) so you cannot use a closed form solution. In those cases, gradient descent is used to find some good local optimum points. Or if you want to implement an online version then again you have to use a gradient descent based algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can solve your linear regression problem by different methods: normal equations (the way you mentioned), QR/SVD decomposition or an iterative method to minimize the error directly (like what the gradient descent method is doing).

Note that the other methods give you the exact solution (ignoring the round-off error) while, as the GD method is iterative, you should be careful in choosing the step size to converge to the correct solution. The advantage of an iterative method is that if your system is really large, you will get a good approximation to your solution much faster.